# Why elem.innerHTML do not set style.display property for created element?

Tags: innerhtml, createelement

I have code. It work sex years ago

```
var elem= doc.createElement( '<span>' );
elem.innerHTML= text;
```

if text is `<div align="center" valign="center" style="display: run-in;"></div>`
I can inspect that elem.firstChild.align is OK, but elem.firstChild.style.display and elem.firstChild.valign are null,

Why? what is changed? How to create and assign values as I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The js engine isn't letting you set a value that isn't supported.

`run-in` wasn't fully supported and so if you did:

```
elem.firstChild.style.display = 'run-in';
// then do 
elem.firstChild.style.display; // the outcome/result is ""
```

however if you use a supported value:

```
elem.firstChild.style.display = 'inline';
// then 
elem.firstChild.style.display;// displays "inline"
```

Check support for the browser you are using to confirm. webkit did initially support it, Mozilla didn't (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=127874). May have been dropped now in chrome and shouldn't be used if you are looking at keeping things consistent across browsers.